# Bootstrap alignment with multiple columns

Tags: spring-boot, twitter-bootstrap-3, thymeleaf

[image]

I just can't find a way to set the top of the right hand column text and top of the left hand column at just the same level.

Here is the code where I used "everything":

```js
<div class="container" style="background: white">

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align: top; background: yellow; border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px ;">
   <h4 style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0px; background: whitesmoke; border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">First Left Heading</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10">

    <p th:each="paragraph : ${resumeMap.get('personal').get('interests')}" th:text="${paragraph}">default str</p>

  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It says “background:yellow” in your inline styles

Comment: Sorry, my question is not accurate: I will change it. My problem is the alignment, not the yellow color. I used yellow background in order to figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Try adding margin-top:-10 to the inline styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap adds `10px` to `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` on heading elements (`<h1>` to `<h6>`). So, if you want text aligned on top, you will need to add this same `margin-top` on the first `<p>` or alternatively add a `10px` `padding-top` on the `col-xs-10` class:

**Example 1: Using `margin-top:10px`**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container" style="background:white">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-2 bg-warning">
      <h4 style="background:whitesmoke;">First Left Heading</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10 bg-info">
      <p style="margin-top:10px">first paragraph</p>
      <p>Second paragraph</p>
      <p>Third paragraph</p>
      <p>Four paragraph</p>
      <p>Five paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example 2: Using `padding-top:10px`**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container" style="background:white">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-2 bg-warning">
      <h4 style="background:whitesmoke;">First Left Heading</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10 bg-info" style="padding-top:10px;">
      <p>first paragraph</p>
      <p>Second paragraph</p>
      <p>Third paragraph</p>
      <p>Four paragraph</p>
      <p>Five paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```